# Use Selenium in Python 3.6 to click on 'Next page of results' button

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click the next button on this website (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/?term=corn) but cannot find the right terminology to use the Selenium toolset appropriately.

Currently, my code is very bulky but this is the line I'm having issues with

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="pagination"] <THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP!> )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath presently will select all divs with the class "pagination".

To find the next page link, you can use the xpath `//a[@title="Next page of results"]`

Your final code may end up looking like this:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="Next page of results"]').click()
```

Comment: I did try what you recommended and got this error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //a[@title="Next page of results"]

I believe it is because the link is buried beneath javascript? I am still new and am unsure about this though.

Comment: Are you using any sort of wait? It's working for me so I suspect that it's executing before the page has fully loaded. There's more information regarding waits here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html